# How to make a List with months from current to previous etc.. Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i can think how can you make a list with months from current'octomber' to previous etc etc, this list can have 12 months from now octomber 2022 to november 2021.
not hardcoded, automated.

Comment: what do you mean by `not hardcoded, automated`?

Comment: automated each month the list get updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package like this:

```
List months = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var monthNumber = (DateTime.now().month - i);
  var monthDate = DateFormat.M().parse(
      (monthNumber < 1 ? 12 - (-monthNumber) : monthNumber).toString());
  var year = DateTime.now().month - i < 1
      ? DateTime.now().year - 1
      : DateTime.now().year;
  var month = DateFormat.MMMM().format(monthDate);
  months.add('$year $month');
}
print("months = $months");//months = [2022 October, 2022 September, 2022 August, 2022 July, 2022 June, 2022 May, 2022 April, 2022 March, 2022 February, 2022 January, 2021 December, 2021 November]
```

if you get your list in Int try this:

```
List months = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var monthNumber = (DateTime.now().month - i);
  var month = (monthNumber < 1 ? 12 - (-monthNumber) : monthNumber);
  months.add(month);
}
print("months = $months");//months = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11]
```

Comment: how can i make the same with numbers?
print("months = $months");//months = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11]

Comment: Check my updated @BillTertis

Comment: any way to add year next to month?

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @BillTertis

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
void main() {
  List<String> months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ];
  
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    
  print(months);

  var result=(months
                ..addAll(months.getRange(0, now.month))
                ..removeRange(0,now.month)
             )
            .reversed.toList();
 
  
  
  print(result);
}
```